# Round of 2 decimal is not happening in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I am doing below calculation in databricks and rounding off to 2 decimal points.

```
result = (
    round(
        coalesce(
            when(col('col') != 0, col('col')),
            when(col('col') != 0, col('col')),
            when(col('col') != 0, col('col')),
            when(col('col') != 0, col('col'))
        ) * col('col4') +
        when((col('col') > 0) & (col('col') > 0), col('col') * col('col')).otherwise(col('col')),
        2
    )
    .alias('col')
)
```

and my code is working fine,but for one record it is not rounding off correctly

example 216.495 it should be round off 216.50 , in output it showing 216.49

Comment: Are you dealing with float values?

Comment: are you aware of this general phenomenon: [is floating-point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: You change type to doubletype.

Comment: doubletype where

Comment: @SalmanA yes i am dealing with floating values

Comment: Boom. Then 216.495 could actually be 216.4949951171875 which is rounded to 216.49

Comment: no after doing calculation i am getting 216.495,so it should be 216.50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of the column to `DoubleType` or convert to `DecimalType` scaling to `3`.

It gives expected results.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, coalesce, when,round
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, DoubleType,FloatType,DecimalType

data = [
    (216.495,)
]

schema = StructType([
    StructField("col", DoubleType(), True)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
df.select(round(col("col"),2).alias("col")).display()
```

Or

```py
data = [
    (216.495,)
]

DecimalType()
schema = StructType([
    StructField("col", FloatType(), True)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
df.select(round(col("col").cast(DecimalType(scale=3)),2)).display()
```

Output:

| col |
| --- |
| 216.5 |

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to cast to float and then to decimal:

```
df = df.withColumn("col", col("col").cast("float").cast("decimal(3,2)"))
```